# Spring Cloud 2022 Config Client fails to connect to Config Server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

**Running with Spring Boot v3.0.4, Spring v6.0.6, JDK1.17**

Clients are failing to connect to configuration server running on the standard port, 8888.
There is no security on the configuration server. The server's actuator endpoint are accessible at http://localhost:8888/config-server/health...

As expected, if the client is set to spring.cloud.config.fail-fast=false then the client starts.

Of note when I add an application-local.yml and change the spring.config.import to my hostname, the client cycles through the local profile, fails and then tries the default, then fails fast.

**Server:**

```
spring:
  application:
    name: config-server
  cloud:
    bus:
      enabled: true
      id: ${spring.application.name}
  rabbitmq:
    host: localhost
    port: 5672
    username: guest
    password: guest
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri:  file:///c:\\projects\\my-configurations

server:
  port: 8888
  servlet:
    context-path: /${spring.application.name}
```

```
... Running with Spring Boot v3.0.4, Spring v6.0.6
... Tomcat started on port(s): 8888 (http) with context path '/my-config-server'
... Creating binder: rabbit
... Constructing binder child context for rabbit
... Caching the binder: rabbit
... declaring queue for inbound: springCloudBus.anonymous.j-rYOoG8QBeDzjd09_XQog, bound to: springCloudBus
... Attempting to connect to: [localhost:5672]
... Created new connection: rabbitConnectionFactory#5f3ddc86:0/SimpleConnection@147aceec [delegate=amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/, localPort=64960]
... Channel 'rabbit-1425418950.springCloudBusInput.errors' has 1 subscriber(s).
... Channel 'rabbit-1425418950.springCloudBusInput.errors' has 2 subscriber(s).
... started bean 'inbound.springCloudBus.anonymous.j-rYOoG8QBeDzjd09_XQog'
... Started MyConfigApplication in 7.843 seconds (process running for 8.249)
```

The server actuator endpoints are accessible.

**Client POM:**

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <!-- CLOUD PROPERTY MANAGEMENT -->
        <!-- Spring Configuration Client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Cloud Bus config refresh -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

**Client application.yml**

```
spring:
  application:
    name: gdelt-ingest
import
  config:
    import: "optional:configserver:"
```

Client Results

```
... Starting application com.bar.gdelt.mapper.GdeltMapperApplication with URLs [file:/C:/projects/gdelt-mapper/target/classes/]
... Retry: count=0
... Retry: count=0
... Fetching config from server at : http://localhost:8888
... Checking for rethrow: count=1
... Retry: count=1
... Retry: count=1
... Fetching config from server at : http://localhost:8888
... Checking for rethrow: count=2
... Retry: count=2
... Retry: count=2
... Fetching config from server at : http://localhost:8888
... Checking for rethrow: count=3
... Retry failed last attempt: count=3
... Application run failed
org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigClientFailFastException: Could not locate PropertySource and the fail fast property is set, failing: None of labels [] found
        at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServerConfigDataLoader.doLoad(ConfigServerConfigDataLoader.java:199)
        at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigClientRetryBootstrapper.lambda$initialize$0(ConfigClientRetryBootstrapper.java:
```

Comment: You have to either remove the context from config server or tell the client there is a context. On mobile so can't find docs for client

Comment: Thanks for lending an eye @spencergibb. I attempted that once before but apparently didn't have all the profiles set up correctly or forgot to recompile the default properties.

Answer (score 0):

Since I specified an application name in the Config Server, it requires a full URL in the client. For which I should have caught when testing the Config Server actuator endpoints, http://localhost:888/config-server/health

**Config Server**

```
spring:
  application:
    name: config-server
```

**Client**

```
spring:
  application:
    name: gdelt-mapper
    config:
      fail-fast: true
      retry:
        initial-interval: 1000
        max-attempts: 3
  config:
    import: "optional:configserver:http://localhost:8888/config-server"
```